# Python - how to reduce a list and keep values?

Tags: python, list, merge, boxplot

I have a list looking like that:

```
[[12, 0.029], [12, 0.039], [12, 0.012], ...some hundreds more... [13, 0.04], [13, 0.01], ...]
```

The first values range from 3 to 15, with an overall count of about 3000 values

For boxplotting I would need a solution where a boxplot is created for each first value with all second values. Like:

```
data_to_plot = [ all second values of list with value 12], [all second values of list with value 13],...
```

Looking like:

```
data_to_plot = [0.029, 0.039], [0.04, 0.01],...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does the ordering of the second values matter?

Comment: No, it does not, as they are used as data points for a boxplot

Comment: There are n or hundreds of values for [12, ****]. Not only two for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want a dictionary with the first values as keys and the second values as elements of a list.  You could do something like:

```
data_dict = {}
for key, value in list:
    if key not in data_dict:
        data_dict.update({key: [value]})
    else:
        data_dict[key].append(value)
```

This will yield (using your example data) `{12: [0.029, 0.039], 13: [0.04, 0.01]}`

Comment: as shown by the answer of AndreyT this works with `data_to_plot=data_dict.values()`

Answer (score 1):

Use a `defaultdict` with default as `list` so you don't need to check if a key already exists. Then collect values using the first items as keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

lst = [[12, 0.029], [12, 0.039], [13, 0.04], [13, 0.01]]
for l in lst:
    result[l[0]].append(l[1])

print(list(result.values()))
# [[0.029, 0.039], [0.04, 0.01]]
```

In this way, you still know which `values` belong to which `keys`.

```
data_to_plot = result.values()
keys_for_data = result.keys()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterators (but the list with pairs should have an even length):

```
data = [[12, 0.029], [12, 0.039], [13, 0.04], [13, 0.01]]
iter_second = (x[1] for x in data)
#py2
data_to_plot = zip(*([iter_second]*2))
#py3
data_to_plot = tuple(zip(*([iter_second]*2)))
```

> But here can be n values starting with 12

```
data = [[12, 0.029], [12, 0.039], [12, 0.012], [13, 0.04], [13, 0.01]]
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, val in data:
    d[key].append(val)
# if you need same order as in `data` use OrderedDict with setdefault method
data_to_plot = d.values()
# Output: [[0.029, 0.039, 0.012], [0.04, 0.01]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Suppose your data (a list of lists) is sorted by the first value.

```
import itertools
import operator

lists = [[12, 0.029], [12, 0.039], [12, 0.052], [13, 0.04], [13, 0.01], [13, 0.066]]

data_to_plot = list()
for name, group in itertools.groupby(lists, key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    data_to_plot.append(map(operator.itemgetter(1), group))

print(data_to_plot)
# Output
[[0.029, 0.039, 0.052], [0.04, 0.01, 0.066]]
```

---

If the sublists are not presorted, you should sort them before `groupby`,

```
data_to_plot = list()
for name, group in itertools.groupby(sorted(lists), key=operator.itemgetter(0)):
    data_to_plot.append(map(operator.itemgetter(1), group))

print(data_to_plot)
# Output
[[0.029, 0.039, 0.052], [0.01, 0.04, 0.066]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like (the other answers weren't aware that you only want to have data points with 12 as the first value):

```
data = [[12, 0.029], [12, 0.039], [13, 0.04], [13, 0.01]]

items = []
points = [point[1] for point in data if point[0] == 12]
for i in range(0, len(points), 2):
    try:
        items.append([points[i], points[i+1]])
    except IndexError:
        pass

print items
# [[0.029, 0.039]]
```

Additionally, what should be done with lists with an odd number of data points?